# Display database value based on which radio button is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am suppose to display the database values in a gridview based on which radio button is selected. I'm currently using a RadioButtonList and I'm supposed to display certain transactions based on the transaction date they select in the radio button. For example, if they select View past 1 Month transaction, my gridview is suppose to show only the past one month transaction. I'm currently using C#.

The date is retrieved base on system date and are recorded when there are transactions made. May I know how to link the radio transaction with the database using gridview ?

First page:

[image]

Second page, with the result here based on the selection from the first page:

[image]

This is my coding for the gridview.

```
     myConnection.ConnectionString = strConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT thDate, thType, thAmountIn, thAmountOut from [Transaction] ORDER BY thDate, thType, thAmountIn, thAmountOut DESC", myConnection);
    myConnection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataSource = reader1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Add some code so that we have something to go on. Also, what have you tried? Without seeing any code, I would say something like `if(radioButton1.Checked == true)` and then put the code for pulling your data inside that `if` statement.

Comment: I haven't done anything to link between the radio button and grid view. I've only retrieve the data from database to gridview. The Gridview is to be shown in the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Given that I cannot see any code of yours:

On OnSelectedIndexChanged event of the RadioButtonList you can pick up which radio button was selected using RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value

Then you can make a Sql query using to get the results back and bind it to your Datagrid

**Example :**

```
//This is the method for event OnSelectedIndexChanged 
void Index_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value use the value
   and to built as sql query string on your sqldatasource
  //Execute 
  //attach datasource to datagrid
  //Databind datagrid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw this in the comments:

> the gridview and the radio button is on 2 different page

That's information you should really include in the question. But I can work with this.

To start, you want code like this in whatever part of your page handles the action where you decide you want to move to the page with the gridview:

```
var radioListMap = new Dictionary<string, string> 
{
   {"Current Month",                "0"},
   {"Last 1 Month & Current Month", "1"},
   {"Last 2 Month & Current Month", "2"}
};

string monthsBack;
if (!radioListMap.TryGetValue(radioListButton1.SelectedValue.Text, out monthsBack))
{
    monthsBack = "0";
}

Response.Redirect("MyOtherPage.aspx?MonthsBack=" + monthsBack);
```

You can see here how this encodes a value based on the radio button into a URL query parameter. Note I used a string at this point instead of an int, because we need a string for the URL anyway. You could also put this in the `Session` if you wanted, instead of the URL, in which case an `int` might be better.

Now, in the page with the gridview, the code needs to look something like this:

```
int monthsBack = int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["monthsBack"], out monthsBack) ? monthsBack : 0;

DateTime minDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1).AddMonths(-monthsBack);

string SQL = @"
SELECT thDate, thType, thAmountIn, thAmountOut
FROM [Transaction] 
WHERE thDate >= @MinThDate 
ORDER BY thDate, thType, thAmountIn, thAmountOut DESC";

using var myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
using var cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MinThDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = minDate;

myConnection.Open();
var reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
GridView1.DataSource = reader1;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

You can put this code somewhere like `Page_Load`

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
DataTable table= new DataTable("table");
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(@"Your Connection Stuff;"))
{
if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
{
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM yourdatabase WHERE date = " + date, sqlConn))
{
da.Fill(table);
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}
```

This links the table to the data grid:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

**Example based on your code:**

You can get the current date like this:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
```

Your sql command would become:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT thDate, thType, thAmountIn, thAmountOut from [Transaction] WHERE thDate = " + date + " ORDER BY thDate, thType, thAmountIn, thAmountOut DESC", myConnection);
```

You can implement the if statements like so:

```
if(radioButton1.Checked == true)
{
cmd += " WHERE thDate = " + date + ";
}
```

Comment: hi, May i know which page to put the code in ? Because the gridview and the radio button is on 2 different page .

Comment: @KYQ You should have to put it in the page with the radioButton. You may need to transfer some data from one page to another if it doesnt work. Let me know and I can teach you how to do that.

Comment: Hi, I don't need the current date time. The date should be based on the date in the transaction history. My database had different dates for few months. However I would only like to retrieve the month based on the radio button selected. Thank You

Comment: @KYQ If I understand correctly, you should do this: `if(radioButton2.Checked == true) { DateTime d = DateTime.today; d.AddMonths(-1); }`

Comment: hi, But how do I link it to the gridview which is next page?

Comment: @KYQ Since I cant go into great detail about that in a comment, go [here](http://codeincsharp.blogspot.com/2008/04/how-to-pass-values-to-another-form.html) and read that page.

Comment: **NOOOOOO!** Do **NOT** do it this way. Use parameterized queries, even for DateTime values!